# Math operation with 16b hex in python

Tags: python, math, hex

I have a start hex : "00000000FFFFFFFF000000000AF50AF5" on this one I want to perform some operations.
User enter an int value (20 for exemple).
Program do : input*100. (=2000)
Convert it in "Hex Little Endian"(=D0070000)
Replace the first 4bytes (00000000) by this new 4bytes: (=D0070000FFFFFFFF000000000AF50AF5)
**Until here It's good ! Problems begin now.**
Replace same hex (=D0070000) at the third position of 4bytes(00000000): (=D0070000FFFFFFFFD00700000AF50AF5)
And finally substract this same hex (=D0070000) to the second postion of 4bytes (FFFFFFFF): (=2FF8FFFF)
Final hex : "D00700002FF8FFFFD00700000AF50AF5"

I don't understand how can I mention to my program the position of 4bytes (1,2,3 or 4)to replace.

```
user_int_value=int(input("enter num: "))*100 #user input*100
start_hex=bytes.fromhex("00000000FFFFFFFF000000000AF50AF5") #Starting hex
num_tot=hex(int.from_bytes(user_int_value.to_bytes(16, 'little'), 'big')) #convert user input to hex in little endian
sum = hex(int('0xFFFFFFFF', 16) - int(num_tot, 16)) #substract same hex to "0xFFFFFFFF"
```

## EDIT

More simply i want to combine 4bytes :

```
data = ["0xD0070000", "0x2FF8FFFF", "0xD0070000", "0x0AF50AF5"]
```

final result I want "0xD00700002FF8FFFFD00700000AF50AF5"

Comment: Why are you calling an integer `str`? That's even more confusing than the usual mistake of calling a string `str`, on top of hiding the built-in `str` type.

Comment: The things you're referring to are not bytes. A byte consists of two hex digits, not 8.

Comment: And why are you not doing anything with `start_hex`?

Comment: @user2357112 right thx for it. Yeah sorry I'm talking about 4byte not one. Now fixed. Because I don't have any idea how to perform on my programm what I want :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = ["0xD0070000", "0x2FF8FFFF", "0xD0070000", "0x0AF50AF5"]
output = hex(int(data[0], 16) << 96 | int(data[1], 16) << 64 | int(data[2], 16) << 32 | int(data[3], 16) << 0)
```

output should become `0xd00700002ff8ffffd00700000af50af5`

In some cases you won't get the output you expect because leading zeros will be chopped off, in that case you can fill the zeros manually doing:

```
print(f"0x{output[2:].zfill(32)}") # Uses f-string (requires newer python versions)
```

or

```
print("0x{}".format(output[2:].zfill(32))) # uses the old python format's string method
```

Comment: Perfect that's what I need ! Last pro when I have this array : data = ["0x00000000", "0x2FF8FFFF", "0x00000000", "0x0AF50AF5"] Output is  0xffffffff000000000af50af5 not 0x00000000ffffffff000000000af50af5. How can I resovle that ?

Comment: You're right, I hadn't considered thoses cases, I've edited my answer, please check it out, now it should work in all cases ;)

Comment: Cool, btw... If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox.